# How do I tell the difference between a small spring under a neighbor's slab and a leak from drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing

I have a French drain between my neighbor and our house. Water is always seeping out of the drain into the street. Upon inspection the water seems to be coming from the corner of the neighbors bathroom because the ground is always wet. I think it is a broken drain pipe under the slab foundation, but they think it is a possibly a natural spring or water seepage from further up the hill in our neighborhood. How do we tell the difference and what damage will this cause the slab?

Comment: Aren't Sinkholes cuased by leaky pipes? https://www.pipespy.com/blog/sinkhole-causes-bad-plumbing

Comment: Do you mean a drain pipe as in their sewer drain?  You should definitely notice an odor if that's the case.  If you suspect a spring, how does it vary with weather and season?  Springs will often flow more in the spring or after periods of sustained rain.

Comment: I'd have the neighbor get a leak test/pressure test on their plumbing before assuming it was a spring.  It's just a lot more common to have a leaky pipe than to just happen to have ground water coming from under the foundation.

Comment: You could take a sample of the water and have tested for fecal bacteria if negative it would be a spring but if positive it could be surface contamination. I think water testing in my area is a arround 15$. Water leaks can erode the soil under the slab but this usually happens on supply lines, a drain would not have much pressure and other than having damp concrete may not affect the slab.

Answer (score 2):

If you think it could be a drain leak (and your neighbor is agreeable to it), you could get some water leak dye and put it in your neighbor's bathroom drains and see if it comes out into the wet ground or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the water is clear and there isn't a sewage smell, it might be a leak. Your neighbor should buy a pressure gauge that will attach to the outside water spigot.

[image: Pressure Gauge]

Once you have the gauge screwed onto the outside spigot, make sure all of the water is off in the home and turn the outside spigot on. The pressure gauge will rise to it's maximum pressure. Leave the valve open. Next, go to the road and turn off the main water supply. Go back and take a look at the gauge reading. If you have a leak, the gauge will drop significantly in a short period of time.

***Concrete Damage*** - Standing water can cause many issues. Concrete is porous and will absorb water. When it stays wet for extended periods, the concrete will begin to break down. In winter months, the water can freeze and expand. This will cause the concrete to crack. The standing water will also (over a long period of time) soften the soil, causing the slab to sink. Cracks in the ceiling or wall could be an indicator that the slab is deteriorating.

Comment: If it is a broken drain line as the op suggest checking the supply won't prove its not a drain but they may discover a leak.